# How to get Billing info in custom email template

Tags: magento-1.9

I send custom email after place order on that i need to add all order conformation details like product name sku, billing info shipping info except Price i need to get every thing

```
 $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                    $emailTemplate->loadByCode('Custom New Order');
                    if(!$emailTemplate->getTemplateId()){
                        continue;
                    }
                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

                    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
                        ->setToName($customerName)
                        ->setToEmail('mymail@gmail.com')
                        ->setFromEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email'))
                        ->setFromName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name'))
                        ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                        ->setSubject($emailTemplate->getTemplateSubject())
                        ->setType('html');

         try {
                    $mail->send();
                } catch (Exception $error) {
                    Mage::log($error->getMessage(), null, 'auto_order_emails.log');
                    continue;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set order object in order template like below and use it in template:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'order'        => $ORDER_OBJECT,
));
```

In you custom email template add below code:

```
<p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
```

Comment: Where i need too can you please tell me after add this it redirect to shopping cart page